# apply global style on selected class

Tags: javascript, angular

While writing a component I want to use a global style for only one specific class name. I know about `ViewEncapsulation.None` but don't want to disable encapsulation for whole component.

How do I apply the global style for `icon-x` which is globally imported in the following template.

```
<i class="icon-x"/>
```

Comment: Styles added to `index.html` are not rewritten and emulated encapsulation doesn't apply to these styles. They will match any element in the page where the selector matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this class and add css reference in root html file(not in component)